# Fabric remove app from one organization and add it to another

Tags: twitter-fabric

What is the proper way of removing existing app from one Fabric organization to another one?

The docs says simply "remove and add to another", but all I could find was a Delete button which will delete the complete app and all its history. I want to keep the history and only want to add some app to another organization.

Comment: Fabric currently don't allow apps to be transferred between Organizations.